# How to decode special characters (blank square unreadable) in c#?

Tags: c#, replace, character

I have a problem that i can manage to resolve, i need to replace unreadable characters (i can't paste it here since it's not taken into acount but it shows like a blank square in the visual C# debugger.

When those are inserted in the sql database they are replaced by a ? but i don't want it... I tried to do a simple replace on the string but visual c# makes the pasting of such characters impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When you see the red squares, you've already lost the relevant character info and you can't convert them back.

Comment: Yeah, that's really anoying! and what's even more anoying is that in visual studio 2008 i was able to do a replace like : mystring.replace("l□","l''") but in visual studio 2010 this square is automatically replaced by a blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace any character if you only know the unicode character code:

```
s = s.Replace('\u0080', ' ');
```

You can use a regular expression to replace any character outside of a set of allowed characters:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^0-9A-Za-z]", " ");
```

Another alternative is to use a unicode data type in the database, so that it can handle any character that you have in your string.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated, well at least i'd like to convert the square in a "'" for sentences that are likely to contains this "'". For instance i can assume that l□amour can be replaced by l'amour. So right now i'm looking for the unicode equivalent (it's not \u0080)

Comment: @talman: Yes, 0080 was just an example; one likely candidate. To find out the character codes to replace you should look into the reason why they are there. If possible you should look earlier in the chain to see if there is a mismatch in encodings that causes those characters to be there in the first place, which could eliminate the problem instead of trying to patch it up.

Comment: yep, i know the problem is that i can't look earlier since i use an api that retrieves me this text, there's no way for me to change anything i'm just retrieving the text. Well think i will have a long way to find the match, outch...

Comment: Finally i found a way to retrieve it thanks to this url http://hapax.qc.ca/conversion.fr.html if it can help other people!